# ASP.NET System.Web.Optimization: Bundling jQueryUI CSS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, bundle, web-optimization

I am trying to bundle jQueryUI in one request.

**Global.asax:**

```
var cssjQuery = new StyleBundle("~/Content/BundleCSS/jQuery");
cssjQuery.IncludeDirectory("~/Content/themes/base", "*.css");
```

**Layout:**

```
<link href="@Styles.Url("~/Content/BundleCSS/jQuery")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Folder structure:**

- **CSS files:** Content/themes/base/*.css
- **Image files:** Content/themes/base/images/*.png

The problem now is that the images can't be loaded, because there is no Folder "BundleCSS":

```
http://localhost:64648/Content/BundleCSS/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why don't you simple define your bundle on the theme directory path:

```
var cssjQuery = new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui-bundle");
cssjQuery.IncludeDirectory("~/Content/themes/base", "*.css");
```

The relative image paths will still work (as the directory of CSS will remain the same).

Also please remember that the last part (`jquery-ui-bundle`) is being treated as the file name so it can be whatever you want (as long as it is not the same as one of the files).

Comment: Phew... finally got it to work! Crazy that the default defined by the ASP.NET team doesn't work out of the box when the app is deployed to IIS. Thanks bro.

Comment: Also please remember that the last part (jquery-ui-bundle) is being treated as the file name so it can be whatever you want (as long as it is not the same as one of the files). <- this saved a lot of brain cells